# Setting a spinner selected item by JSON

Tags: android, json, spinner

I am making an android app that asks for the users to select a country and city via spinner.

First , I get data from json , like this :

```
String state = json.data.getState();

String city = json.data.getCity();
```

When the user opens the app first time, spinner value is String state and String city , here is my code :

```
 final List<State> statesList = new ArrayList<>();
 final List<String> states = new ArrayList<>();

 final StateAdapter stateAdapter = new StateAdapter(this,
            R.layout.state_list, R.id.spinnerText, statesList);
 SpinnerCity.setAdapter(stateAdapter);
 SpinnerCity.setSelect(String state); //????
 SpinnerCity.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){
  @Override
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
     State cityDetails = stateAdapter.getItem(position);
     List<String> cityList = cityDetails.getCities();
     ArrayAdapter citiesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                    R.layout.city_list, R.id.citySpinnerText, cityList);
     SpinnerArea.setAdapter(citiesAdapter);
     SpinnerArea.setSelected(String city); //??? 
    }

class StateAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<State> {

 private List<State> stateList = new ArrayList<>();

 public StateAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, int spinnerText, @NonNull List<State> stateList) {
    super(context, resource, spinnerText, stateList);
    this.stateList = stateList;
 }
 @Override
 public State getItem(int position) {
     return stateList.get(position);
 }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull 
    ViewGroup parent) {
        return initView(position);
    }
    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    return initView(position);
    } 

    private View initView(int position) {
    State state = getItem(position);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.state_list, null);
    TextView textView =  view.findViewById(R.id.spinnerText);
    textView.setText(state.getStateName());
    return view;
    }
```

I just don't know how to put String in Spinner at first?
by the way , user also can change state and city via spinner,
I will save change info into a object.Thanks.

[Edit]
I know how to setSelection , for example:

```
    int position = stateAdapter.getPosition(statesList.get(3));
    stateSpinner.setSelection(position);
```

if I get json's data is String, how do I know statesList.get(?)

Strange ? When I get String "Kaohsuing" , I am try to find position in ArrayList, but I always get -1 , that mean String is no matching Arraylist Data.

My mistake , if I want to find state position ,  solution is:

```
      List<String> states = new ArrayList<>(); 
      int cityPosition = states.indexOf(City); 
      SpinnerCity.setSelection(cityPosition);
```

Comment: can you share your JSON response

Comment: You mean, trying to display "state" String as first value and followed by API data in spinner right?

Comment: my json's data is : {"city":"Taipei", "area":["Jhongshan","Songshan"]}
I know the key is StateAdapter , but I don't know how to edit ?

Comment: @Arjun G : Yes , I try to put String into Spinner.setselection(String,true) , but seems can't put String in Spinner.setselection, it's need int.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the position of your item inside the adapter

```
int vPos = stateAdapter.getPosition("myStringValue");
```

Then you can set default value like that

```
SpinnerCity.setSelection( vPos );
```

Good luck !

Comment: should I rewrite  class StateAdapter ??

Comment: Sorry the method is "getPosition" not "get" simply mistake try this

Comment: String State = json.getData.getCountry();
int position = stateAdapter.getPosition(City);  //error

Comment: Can you post the error ? Do you call methods after SpinnerCity.setAdapter(stateAdapter); ?

Comment: it will ask mt to create method getPosition in StateAdapter

Comment: getPosition it's a method from ArrayAdapter. In ur StateAdapter class you can override this method then you can use it :@Override public int getPosition( @Nullable String item )
 {
 return super.getPosition( item );
 }

Comment: Seems String can just put in getPosition. Does any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is to grab the position of the state from you adapter by `state` value.
For example:

```
int position = stateAdapter.getPosition(state);
SpinnerCity.setSelection(position)
```

to make this work properly the value in state and in adapter should be equal.
if they not equal the position will not be returned correctly.

Comment: in StateAdapter class , I don't have "getItemPosition" ?

Comment: int position = stateAdapter.getPosition(state); where is state??
because String State = json.getData.getCountry , if I put String State , it will be get error

Comment: it will ask mt to create method getPosition in StateAdapter

Comment: I also see you are making compile error here: `(String state)` you cannot provide value like this, you should init state first : `String state = json.getData.getCountry; and then call stateAdapter.getPosition(state)`

Comment: you don't have to create method getPosition(), ArrayAdapter already have it

Comment: like you said , init String State , String State = json's data , and I can see State is really have value , it String , then I call int position = stateAdapter.getPosition(City), it will show " getPosition in StateAdapter cannot be applied to java.lang.String"

Comment: Why City?? and look at this ` spinnerArea.setSelected(String city);` this is wrong Java not working like this. You should provide only the reference of city not String city.

Comment: , you are right , but I get state data is String , I don't know how to change String to int ? that's why int position = stateAdapter.getPosition(City); is always get error messages.

Comment: Seems like we speak in different languages, sorry i can't explain more detailed then this.

Comment: That's OK , You do really help me very much, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> > You can't set Spinner adapter with arraylist of custom model class
> >     type, List statesList.
> >
> > ```
> > Instead set adapter with List<String>:
> > ```
>
> ```
>      List<String> stateNames = new ArrayList();
>
>  add stateName to the above arrayList from statesList;
>
> Set this arrayList to state Spinner as Adapter.
> ```

```
  SpinnerCity.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){
  @Override
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
     State cityDetails = statesList.get(position); // here do like this
     List<String> cityList = cityDetails.getCities();
     ArrayAdapter citiesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                    R.layout.city_list, R.id.citySpinnerText, cityList);
     SpinnerArea.setAdapter(citiesAdapter);
  //   SpinnerArea.setSelected(String city); // Remove this, no use
    }
```

Comment: I know SpinnerArea.setSelected(String city) is wrong. so I edit my code like : int position = stateAdapter.getPosition(statesList.get(3)); //I can get position,then : stateSpinner.setSelection(position);//no question , but I don't know json's data postition?